# MVC5 upload large file to DB System.OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I need to upload potentially large files to our site, and then into the database. However every time I instantiate the byte[] that stores the file data, I get an immediate System.OutOfMemoryException.  The box has sufficient ram, but IIS/.Net appear to have limits on process memory.

Model:

```
public class CreateFileModel : IFileModel {
...
       [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
       public byte[] FileData { get; set; }
...
}
```

Post Action:

```
[HttpPost]
       [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
       public ActionResult CreateFile(CreateFileModel model) {
          try {

             if (ModelState.IsValid && Request != null && Request.Files.Count > 0) {

                foreach (string uploadname in Request.Files) {
                    HttpPostedFileBase uploadedFile = Request.Files[uploadname];
                    if (uploadedFile?.ContentLength > 0) {  
                       model.FileData = new byte[uploadedFile.ContentLength];  // <-- BREAKS HERE WITH OutOfMemoryException
                       uploadedFile.InputStream.Read(model.FileData, 0, Convert.ToInt32(uploadedFile.ContentLength));
                    }
                }

                if (model.FileData.Length > 0) {
                    FileMapper mapper = new FileMapper();
                    mapper.Create(model);

                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Index", new { pucoId = CurrentUser.PUCOID, folderId = CurrentDirectoryId });
                }
             }

          }
          catch (Exception ex) {
             OnError(ex);
          }

          model.FileData = null;
          return View(model);
       }

    }
```

The error always happens when instantiating the receiving buffer in the model, which will be used to update the database.

```
model.FileData = new byte[uploadedFile.ContentLength];
```

So I'm trying to figure out where to go from here. I could save the file to the filesystem using a smaller buffer, but then I could never actually get it into the database.

How would you tackle this issue?

Comment: Is a bad practice upload files directly to Database. Instead, save to a folder and add the path to your database.

Comment: That will involve rewriting large chunks of the application, and in point of fact, it is discouraged to maintain large file hierarchies linked to data, as it is a significant task to maintain the integrity of the data across the DB and filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the size of the private memory limit for your application pool in IIS this should show you how to do this https://www.404techsupport.com/2016/03/iis-wsus-private-memory/

Secondly, how large are your files??

Can you split them up into smaller files that are then combined once server side?

Comment: I'd like to support up to 4GB, but I think 1GB is minimally acceptable. As for chuncking the files, I still need to reassemble them to fill the model field in order to get them into the DB, so I will always need to be able to create a buffer in which to combine them before they can be inserted to the DB. or do you have any idea to get around this?

Comment: Is there a reason why you do not want to FTP upload the files to the server?  There is another way suggested here in this post to might be able to help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17527365/memory-usage-if-upload-big-file-in-one-request-in-iis

Comment: well, upload isn't the issue, but instead creating a buffer to hold the data so it can then be inserted into the DB. I'm afraid I don't see how using FTP would change that. Am I missing somthing?  Setting the AppPool memory may help, but I'm still trying to figure out how you configure that in IISExpress on my development workstation. Any hints on that?